# Woocommerce local pick shipping method show new field in checkout under the chosen method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wonder if someone can help me out with woocommerce local pick shipping method.

What I want to achive is to show the new field I added inside the shipping method at the checkout page.

For example I added the field **My additional information** where you can type the street adress etc.

[image]

The problem is , its not showing in the checkout page as you can see below.

[image]

The file is here ,code a little to long to paste it .
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/shipping/local-pickup/class-wc-shipping-local-pickup.php

Maybe some of you knows how to use this **hook** ?
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Local_Pickup.html

Thank you very much.